# How to access Data of all AWS RDS Reserved Instances using java?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I dont know how to access only rds reserved instance data in java. Can anyone please provide so that i can access the rds reserved instance data.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This

```
AmazonRDS client = new AmazonRDSClient();
DescribeReservedDBInstancesRequest request = new DescribeReservedDBInstancesRequest()
    .withDBInstanceClass("db.t2.micro").withDuration("1y")
    .withMultiAZ(false).withOfferingType("No Upfront")
    .withProductDescription("mysql");
DescribeReservedDBInstancesResult response = client
    .describeReservedDBInstances(request);
```

You May Read Other Methods in this link 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/rds/AmazonRDSClient.html